# How to do timing tasks in Python, for a system holding one million users?

Tags: python, redis, server, celery

leave out of cron command in unix.

***Situations*** are bellow:

- Users in total, about one million right now, and will grow to about 3 million in one year;
- Timing tasks type: notification, calculation, upload data and so on;
- Timing interval: from several minutes to one month;
- Different tasks may have different logic and parameters;

***requirements*** are bellow:

- Better if can get it done in python, for the server code is Python;
- The timing tolerance can be within 5 seconds, say if a task should be executed at 2015-01-01T00:00:00, it's ok to get it done from 2014-12-31T12:59:55 to 2015-01-01T00:00:05;
- Log details for each task for each user, can debug in the future;
- Can persist the task details info, for the server maybe down for some reasons;
- If the server is down, can restart the tasks after re-firing up the server;

thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous; Do you want to run the tasks due to some event or is it timely. Logging can be left to Redis (HyperLogs) and Redis is cluster based (async persistent) so you can restart your app of you keep the tiers on different servers (if server crashes are a concern)

Comment: you've tagged your question with "celery" so I assume you are aware of celerybeat - in what ways does it not meet your needs?

Answer (score 2):

You could check [fantail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fantail)

You can create multiple Fantails to accommodate your different requirements and also see the Pickers

```
var sch = new Fantail({
  debug: false,     // Expose queues and handlers. 
  throttle: 200,    // Run handlers (at most once) every 200 milliseconds 
  immediate: false  // .start() immediately. 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `schedule` module is what you are looking for :

```
import schedule
import time

def foo():
    print "Hello world !"

schedule.every(1).minutes.do(foo)

# You can do the following in another thread.
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: yeah, that's too lightweight for me. I just edit some details for the question, thank you so much